# What's the right way to send a multi dimensional array from a python script to a C++ code using NamedPipes?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pipe

I have a C++ code that expects a struct with this exact formate to be send to it through a NamedPipe:-

```
struct InputData {
  const std::array<std::array<float, 4>, 5> flexion;
  const std::array<float, 5> splay;
  const float joyX;
  const float joyY;
  const bool joyButton;
  const bool trgButton;
  const bool aButton;
  const bool bButton;
  const bool grab;
  const bool pinch;
  const bool menu;
  const bool calibrate;

  const float trgValue;
};
```

I am using a python script to extract this info and then packing it using the struct python library and send it to the C++ script:-

```
def encode(flexions, splay, joys, bools):
    
    if splay is None:
        splay = [0.0] * 5

    if joys is None:
        joys = [0.0] * 2

    if bools is None:
        bools = [False] * 8

    packed_flexions = struct.pack('@20f', *flexions)
    packed_splays = struct.pack('@5f', *splay)
    packed_joys = struct.pack('@2f', *joys)
    packed_bools = struct.pack('@8?', *bools)
    packed_padded = struct.pack('@f', 0.0)

    data = packed_flexions + packed_splays + packed_joys + packed_bools + packed_padded
    return data
```

The "flexion" variable is actually a 4×5 2D vector, and I have no idea how to send it through the struct library, so I flattened it (so now it's a 20 element python list) and packed it's elements one by one and send it but that raised an error in the C++ code.

So what I am doing wrong here? is the problem with the C++ script or my python implementation?

In the c++ code, the ReadFile function return 0 bytes afetr reading the message, so it receives it, but reads zeros bytes from it, I don't know why.

Comment: C++ code is not generally referred  to as script, by the way. If the data is not martialized before transfer, you need to know how your C++ toolchain encodes that `struct`. PLZ be more specific; provide the error details.

Comment: The problem is that the C++ code that encodes is not mine and I don't understand it yet, all i know is the format it accepts, i will try to post the portion i think it's responsible for this.

Comment: @Red.Wave I added it, I can't debug it as the debugging process is complicated, I don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Put the `struct` definition in a C++ program and check `sizeof(InputData)`; use the same toolchain as thr original code. Next compare the outcome with size of your composed python message.

Comment: Ok, I will try that out

Comment: ok I have done an even more deep inspection and found out something interesting, the ReadFile() function return bytes from the pipe normally, and the class state get changed from Reading to Callback, then everything goes alright until the casting
process:-

```
callback_((T*)listenerData.chRequest);
```

the listenerData.chRequest have 120 bytes before the casting process, after the casting process, it returns 8 bytes only...

Comment: So the c++ code receives the full 120 bytes that got send by the python script, but when to start casting them to a struct, something wrong happens and it gets an 8 byte long struct

Comment: So it must be something with how the bytes are structured

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should convert the c++ struct into a serializable form, like JSON or [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).  This way, your python code can deserialize the data into a python friendly object.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

After along time experimenting, the issue was from that I was initializing a new pipe connection every time I send a message to the pipe, so whatever you was sending n dimensions arrays, juts flatten it, this is the right way.

Comment: Can you also share the code that you used to solve the problem?